# Can Psorosis spread via the soil?

Tags: diseases

My citrus tree has Psorosis, and I am thinking about cutting it down and putting a new tree in its place. But I am concerned that the disease will spread via the soil.

Does Psorosis spread through the soil?

(A Psorosis infected tree looks like this: )

[image: Psorosis infected tree]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears not, since this is a virus spread primarily by grafting, and the incidence of the infection has reduced since the use of disease free budwood by growers. There are two forms of the virus; transmission MAY be aerial, but not via roots or soil. It would, though, be wise to remove the tree and its roots prior to planting another.